# Issue in Fetching current timestamp in mysql database column from remote server to local

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've using MySql which is installed in Aws Rds. I've a database with multiple tables in it with a column in common with datatype as timestamp.

Problem is when I insert any record in one of those tables, Timestamp column is inserted automatically with current time. And that's predictable. But, the time is related to place where remote server exists. When I access it locally, I'm getting remote server's local time which I do not want.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting the UTC timezone back unless you've manually [changed the default timezone](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-change-time-zone/) for your RDS instance. In either case, you should be able to predict which timezone the timestamp is going to be in, and convert it to the local timezone on the client side.